# Is there a less verbose way to declare divs, classes, ids and other html elements?

Tags: html, css, preprocessor, markup

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a shorthand for html coding specifically in naming classes and ids or just designating html elements. Currently with regular html i am forced to write:

```
<div class='class1'> <div id='id1'> </div> </div>
```

It seems kind of heavyhanded to me having to write div class='' or div id='' , each time. I keep writing the same type of thing over and over again. I know its normal but it doesnt seem optimal at all. Is there another way this can be written either in standard html, html5  or using a other markup language or preprocessor that still maintains the <> symbols but replaces div class= or div id = with something allittle less verbose? but equally expressive? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to study CSS more extensive. Parts of HTML can changed not only by classes or ids but in the CSS directly. A good planning and formatting of div, p, ul, li, ... directly in the CSS helps to spare most of the class-calls in your HTML-source directly.

Answer (score 4):

You could try an HTML pre-processor such as HAML (http://www.haml.info).

With HAML, your code would go from this:

```html
<div class='class1'> <div id='id1'> </div> </div>
```

to this:

```
.class1
  #id1
```

And something a little more complicated like this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 class="heading title">Heading</h1>
    <p class="paragraph description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

could be written in HAML like this:

```
%html
  %body
    %h1.heading.title Heading
    %p.paragraph.description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to take a look at pug https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Comment: This seems quick and easy to write, but confusing to read afterwards for me unfortunately.  Thank you for the suggestion.